# UITableView one of cell is always opened

Tags: swift, cell

I have 4 custom cells in TableView. Is it possible to make one of cells always open by default when I launch application? Or one cell is always open because of it have some parameter, for example true/false?

Comment: what do you mean by _open_?

Comment: I think he meant "select" a cell. @tereks

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly do you mean by opening a cell.

Comment: With `opened` you mean expanded? If that's the case, it's your responsibility to set the state when answering the delegate method asking for the ViewController for `row` and `indexPath`. You need to take care when selecting another cell, closing the others and so on. But, if you want to show another content based on a clicked cell, I would suggest follow @Sweeper's answer

Comment: Sorry guys for my question without more details. I have some closed cells - http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img924/5855/SRcNgg.png and I want that when app start one of cells must be opened like this - http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img924/1984/8lKbZ1.png The best for me is that one of cells must be opened depending on the time of day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose each of your four cells goes to a different VC when selected?

In `viewDidAppear`, do this:

```
tableView.selectRow(at: someIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
```

This is basically selecting a cell programmatically.

---

With further thought, I think that you should consider using a `UITabBarController` instead. You only have 4 options, and you want one of them to be opened by default. That's exactly what a `UITabBarController` does.